# How can i access the Intel CPU Counter

Tags: performance, cpu

Is there any small tool that gives me access to the data gathered by the Intel CPU Counters (like L1/L2 cache misses, branch prediction failures ... you know there are hunderts of them on modern Core2 CPU's).

It must work on Windows (while being able to use it with Solaris, FreeBSD, Linux, MacOSX would of course be nice).

Comment: Okay in the meantime i found the PAPI library. But this is more or less a Linux only (supporting Solaris only on Sparc) and requires some linux kernel patches - yeah i know Linus said that performance monitoring is one of the two real weaknesses.

And i found perfmon2 and rabbit (a dead project) which are also Linux only.

Not one hit for windows so far.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the Intel PCM (Performance Counter Monitor) tool which does exactly what you want to do.

Link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization

Intel PCM provides a rich API that allows you to instrument your code. Furthermore, to date, PCM is the only tool to read uncore events too.

Answer (score 4):

This thread seems a little old but if you're still interested, I wrote a [howto](http://tech.ryancox.net/2010/11/reading-intel-uncore-performance.html) recently on this topic using nothing more than rdmsr and wrmsr in Linux.  It only deals with the performance counters on an Intel uncore for Westmere, but the process I described might help you figure out what you need if you haven't already.  I'm sure Windows has some equivalent program or function call to RDMSR and WRMSR.  The problem is you need to be ring 0 (kernel mode) to read MSRs.  I have no idea how to do that in Windows.  I won't be able to help with any Windows questions but may be able to answer some MSR-related questions if you have any.  I'm by no means an expert though.

Answer (score 1):

PAPI is a very promising lead, however, I believe they discontinued support for Windows (and therefore .NET C#) quite a few years ago.

On the windows front, Visual Studio 2010 Premium comes with performance explorer. If you run any project or binary in instrumentation mode, you can get access to hardware events such as instructions retired.

The results can be somewhat mixed and inconsistent depending external factors, but it integrates with Visual Studio nicely and you get detailed counts (avg, maximum, total) on a per method/module level.

Intel V-tune performance analyzer also exposes these natively. I haven't played with this tool yet but it might be a more flexible API than what Visual Studio 2010 exposes.

Comment: Thanks but i'm in the business to develop and sell IDE's myself. So this obviously does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write of your are looking for a application or for a library.

For Windows there is Intel VTune. But this not exactly an small tool. For linux I have used oprofile, which works without kernel patches.

Comment: I'm looking for a library because i want to write an instrumenting profiler that records INSTRUCTION_RETIRED events instead of milliseonds. 

Yes and maybe some other things, so you can see it as a small VTune like tool i want to write myself.

Comment: I don't think there is a library. The Performance Monitor Register are accessed via rdmsr and wrmsr instructions.

For a start you may look at the "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developers Manual" (google for the latest version) Volume 3B, Chapter 18.11ff. There is exactly described what you do need to access the Performance Counters.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, Shark lets you get data from the PMCs.  I'm not sure what's available on Windows other than Intel's tools (VTune, as mentioned by drhirsch).

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/
It is a full library that allows you to read any CPU counters data, works both on Windows and Linux [and other OS]

Answer (score 0):

This thread looks pretty old. But still, all the above mentioned counters are available at [Intel PCM](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization) .These counters can be used as a Microsoft Perfmon plugin or a command prompt interface. The Intel PCM gives informations like L2 and L3 cache hit ratio, cache misses etc.